# How to map many URIs using NGINX?

Tags: nginx

I have many UUIDs that refer to a corresponding project path. I am using `rewrite` to map them, as such:

```
rewrite ^/3a498981-a790-50ec-b53d-227e33023564/(.*)$ "/undisclosed/$1" last;
rewrite ^/b78c76de-9ab7-5d0e-81b9-d8b73d8afc4b/(.*)$ "/undisclosed/$1" last;
rewrite ^/1e4d143d-a3ec-5110-80e2-5e5212f93779/(.*)$ "/undisclosed/$1" last;
rewrite ^/858b33b7-bd66-507b-a9f1-533e4de79ba3/(.*)$ "/undisclosed/$1" last;
rewrite ^/451b5b98-4ebb-552d-867d-5dd685cd1810/(.*)$ "/undisclosed/$1" last;
rewrite ^/703dff31-b9be-543f-b6c6-61ae7fb4dd32/(.*)$ "/undisclosed/$1" last;
```

`undisclosed` is always a different path, mapping `/[client name]/[project name]`. However, there are over 90 UUIDs already and this number will grow to 400+ by the end of the year.

Is there a dedicated method to approach this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then:

1. you have 90 different UUIDS (and expect that to number to grow)
2. each UUID maps to a different /clientname/projectname/$1 path

if so, that means you'll have 1 redirect for each UUID, end of story.

you could move the mapping from the webserver to some dynamic page, but that just moves the problem from 1 config to the other (though if you have the mapping defined in some configuration DB already you should be able to automate the mapping by querying it)